# Add a download link to bottom footer area of Woocommerce Category Page

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, custom-taxonomy

I have read a lot of articles on how to add a link but most seem to show how to add a download link to a single product page but what I am trying to achieve is that when a person views for example towels which shows all available towels I want to add a download button at the bottom of the page to download a `towel.pdf`, and if a person clicks on another category for example cloths, there must be a download link at the bottom showing `download pdf` and it must download `cloths.pdf`, so it must be different per category. I am using the Woocommerce storefront theme.

I saw this code but i don't know how to use it as it is my first attempt at making a site with Woocommerce:

```
function wpse_wc_category_footer_link() {
// woocommerce_after_main_content is a generic hook; check we're on a category page.
if ( ! is_product_category() ) {
    return;
} ?>

<!-- Your markup for category pages belongs here... -->
<a href="#">My Link</a>

    <?php    
}
add_action( 'woocommerce_after_main_content', 'wpse_wc_category_footer_link', 5 );
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use the code above as following to add specific link to each category

```
add_action('woocommerce_after_main_content', 'category_links');

function category_links()
{
if (!is_product_category()) { //To add link only to category archive  
  return;
}

if (has_term('towels', 'product_cat')) { //Here you can define which category you want for Example towels
  ?>
<a href="#">Download towel.pdf</a>

<?php }
if (has_term('cloths', 'product_cat')) {
?>
<a href="#">Download cloths.pdf</a>

<?php }


}
```